# Retrieve values from another class

Tags: java, instance

I have a class `Eparams` with a couple of variables with setters and getters:

```
public class Eparams {

    public double alpha;
    public double ep;


    public double getAlpha() {
        return alpha;
    }
    public void setAlpha(double alpha) {
        this.alpha = alpha;
    }

    public double getEp() {
        return ep;
    }

    public void setEp(double ep) {
        this.ep = ep;
    }
```

In another class `Test1` I set values for these variables:

```
Eparams eparams = new Eparams();

eparams.setAlpha(2.51);
eparams.setEp(5.74);
```

In a new class, `Test2`, I want to retrieve those values. Doing the following will give me values of 0 as I'm instantiating a new Eparams object.

```
Eparams eparams = new Eparams();
eparams.getAlpha();
eparams.getEp();
```

How can I retrieve the values of the instance but from another class? I could go down the route of setting the variables and getters/setters to static and not create new objects BUT I want it to be thread safe and allow multiple instances of accessing the variables!

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You can have a singleton, which is a single `Eprams` instance, which is a static member of `Eprams`, but it isn't very different from simply making the fields static.

Comment: To receive the values you need access to the object that holds them. It’s very hard to understand what you’re asking here.

Comment: Pass the instance of `Eparams` from `Test1` to `Test2`

Comment: By calling `Eparams eparams = new Eparams();` in another class you are creating another instance, which has the same properties and methods but not the same values. Consider passing the instance where you set the data to `Test2`

Comment: Different instances will give you different values (unless you set them all the time which doesn't sound practical since you'll have to read them from somewhere else). If you don't want to go static, I guess the question to answer first would be: can you provide more context on who's setting the values and who's reading them?

Answer (score 0):

Pass the values to `Test2` via a constructor:

```
Test2 t2 = new Test2(eparams.getAlpha(), eparams.getEp());
```

And then you have the values in the `t2` object.

Note that this is the initial `eparams` in your code, not the second one.